# Redirect to user.activate if $user->isDisabled() with Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am trying to redirect my users to an activation page (user.activate) if the user isn't activated. I mainly want to do it on login, but an added benefit would be to check it even if the user is logged in.

I tried extending `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker` and returning a RedirectResponse if it catches a DisabledException but it doesn't handle a Response.

I tried checking `if ($user->isDisabled())` in the `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE` and `AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS` events but that doesn't handle a response either.

Answer (score 1):

I added this class

```
class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user->isEnabled())
        {
            // Logout
            $this->app['user.manager']->logout();

            $response = $this->app->redirect($this->app['url_generator']->generate('user.activate', array('id' => $user->id)));
        } 
        else
        {
            // redirect the user to where they were before the login process begun.
            $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');

            $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then added this:

```
$app['security.authentication.success_handler.secured_area'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new \Kidtrips\Lib\LoginSuccessHandler($app);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it related to security, I'd do it another way, with a request listener.

Create a new class with an `onCoreRequest` function, and in the event dispatcher register it for the `kernel.request` event. It will get a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent` instance as the single parameter.

In there you can check if there's a user logged in and if it is disabled, then use the event's `setResponse` event to do a redirect.

Comment: I realized that having it do it on all of the requests is not the best option.